# voting program not working if theres a tie

Tags: java, arrays

this is my array voting program. it works as i wanted but now i need to add new feature to it.
**"If there is a tie, then the program should print the names and votes of the candidates who share the highest votes."**

how should i approach this? my thinking was that i need to find duplicate integers from array and then process them somehow. any ideas you beautiful people, i'm stuck with this part :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraysVoting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number, aanet1, isoin;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of candidates:");
        number = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter candidate's name:");
        String nimi = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Enter " + nimi + "'s votes:");
        aanet1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] votes = new int[number];
        String[] ehdokkaat = new String[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < votes.length - 1; i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter candidate's name:");
            String x = scanner.next();
            ehdokkaat[i] = x;
            System.out.print("Enter " + ehdokkaat[i] + "'s votes:");
            int c = scanner.nextInt();
            votes[i] = c;

        }
        isoin = votes[0];
        int kohta = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < votes.length; i++) {
            if (isoin < votes[i]) {
                isoin = votes[i];
                kohta = votes[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(ehdokkaat[kohta] + " is the winner with " + isoin + " votes!");
    }

}
```

Comment: don't cannibalize your question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program threw exceptions and did not work as expected for me I when I ran it. Here are my modifications

```
    int number, aanet1, isoin;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of candidates:");
    number = scanner.nextInt();

    int[] votes = new int[number];
    String[] ehdokkaat = new String[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter candidate's name:");
        String x = scanner.next();
        ehdokkaat[i] = x;
        System.out.print("Enter " + ehdokkaat[i] + "'s votes:");
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        votes[i] = c;

    }
    isoin = votes[0];
    int kohta = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < votes.length; i++) {
        if (isoin < votes[i]) {
            isoin = votes[i];
            kohta = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(ehdokkaat[kohta] + " is the winner with " + isoin + " votes!");
}
```

- Removed the duplicate logic before the for loop
- In the kohta you do not save the index but the votes of the winner
- The for loop was up to votes.length and although it is correct it is a bit confusing

Now for your question
There are multiple ways to go about it.
The simplest is to iterate through the votes array and find the max value.

Then you iterate again and you save the indexes of the array that have the value .

And then you use those indexes in the ehdokkaat array to find the winners.

You can see if you have a tie, by the amount of items in the array, list or whatever you use. So if it is one you have a winner otherwise there is a tie.

UPDATE:
I wrote it for you, did not test very extensively, I used arrays I hope you are ok with it.

```
    int number, aanet1, isoin;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of candidates:");
    number = scanner.nextInt();
    Integer[] votes = new Integer[number];
    String[] ehdokkaat = new String[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter candidate's name:");
        String x = scanner.next();
        ehdokkaat[i] = x;
        System.out.print("Enter " + ehdokkaat[i] + "'s votes:");
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        votes[i] = c;

    }
    int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(votes));
    List<Integer> winners = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
        if (max == votes[i]) {
            winners.add(i);
        }
    }

    if (winners.size() > 1) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(String.format("Tie (with %d votes) between:", max));
        for (Integer index : winners) {
            System.out.println(ehdokkaat[index]);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(ehdokkaat[winners.get(0)] + " is the winner with " + max + " votes!");
    }
```